# WithEvents Variables cannot be typed as arrays vb.net

Tags: vb.net

```
Private WithEvents btnDeleteRepair_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnDeleteRepair.Click
```

This is the piece of code im working with and it gives me the error "WithEvents Variables cannot be typed as arrays"

Little Background: It's a button inside of a log in view as only admin is to see this button

Comment: Remove `WithEvents`

Comment: @Pikoh this then throws me up the error "'Sender' is not declared. it may be inaccessible due to it's protection level"

Comment: I think you don't have the things clear. What are you trying to do here? Declaring a variable or handling an event?

Comment: You should read [this for example](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/stf7ebaz(v=vs.90).aspx)

Comment: handling an event, will look at that now thanks

Comment: Remove `WithEvents` for method `btnDeleteRepair_Click` and check that variable `btnDeleteRepair` declared with `WithEvents`. For using `Handles control.SomeEvent` - variable should be declared `Private WithEvents control As Button`.

Comment: Another approach: remove `WithEvents` and `Handles btnDeleteRepair.Click` from the method. And add next line in constructor of your form `AddHandler btnDeleteRepair.Click, AddressOf btnDeleteRepair_Click`

Comment: If you're trying to declare a routine named `btnDeleteRepair_Click` then everything else is correct but you need to change `WithEvents` to `Sub`.  `WithEvents` is used to declare a member field that may raise events.  It doesn't belong on subs or functions.

Comment: thanks for the help guys been trying out a few things but just having trouble understanding what im doing. Think i need to revisit my approach perhaps but for now going to move on to something different and come back, can't seem to get anything working without an error message